# Does ngModel or two-way binding take long time in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, two-way-binding, primeng-turbotable

PrimeNG editable table with checkbox

child component

```
<p-table id="resultTable" [columns]="cols" [value]="results" scrollable="true" [resizableColumns]="true" selectionMode="single">
...
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
  ...
    <td>
      <input (click)="checkboxClicked(rowData)" pInputText type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.active">
    </td>
  ...
  </ng-template>
...
</p-table>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './app-child.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-child.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  checkboxClicked(book: Book) {
    console.log('111:', book.active);   //      check the value with ngModel    
    this.checkboxClick.emit(book);
  }
  ...
}
```

parent component

```
...
<app-child (checkboxClick)="checkbox($event)"></app-child>
...
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './app-parent.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

checkboxClickSource = new Subject<Book>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.checkboxClickSource.pipe(
    ...
  ).subscribe(book => {
   console.log('222:', book.active);  //    check the value with ngModel
  });
}


checkbox(book: Book) {
  this.checkboxClickSource.next(book);

}
}
```

Then there's problem very strange to me.
First suppose book.active is true in the beginning.

In IE browser:
the output is: `111: false`
`222: false`

In chrome browser:
 production mode: `111: true`
`222: false`

none production mode:
`111: true`
`222: true`

In IE browser, the ngModel works immediately. But in chrome browser and production mode, the ngModel works when the value has been passed to the parent component, but didn't change in child component. In chrome browser and none production mode, the ngModel doesn't work in both child and parent component.

This is really strange to me and I cannot figure it out. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide a demo?